# How to get prefilled data field values in onsubmit form function in Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript

Iam working in angular4.Here I need to display a form with prefilled data of the user and when user wanted to change the data,I have

```js
 onSubmit(userForm: NgForm) {
    console.log("userform",userForm.value);
             this.next=false;
         var obj = this.storage.retrieve('loginInfo');
         var userId = obj.user_id;
         console.log(userId);
         let headers = new Headers();
         this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
         console.log(userForm.value);
         var location = this.storage.retrieve('location');
    console.log("location",this.information[0].billing.address_1);
         if (this.information[0].billing.address_1!='') {
    console.log("if block");
                 var data = {
             "billing": {
                 "address_1": this.information[0].billing.address1,
                 "address_2": "",
                 "city": this.information[0].billing.city1,
                 "state":this.information[0].billing.state1,
                 "postcode": this.information[0].billing.postCode1,
                 "country": this.information[0].billing.country1,
                 "phone": this.information[0].billing.phone
             },
             "shipping": {
                 "address_1": this.information[0].shipping.address2,
                 "address_2": "",
                 "city": this.information[0].shipping.city2,
                 "state": this.information[0].shipping.state2,
                 "postcode": this.information[0].shipping.postCode2,
                 "country":this.information[0].shipping.country2
             },
         } 
              console.log("data1",data);
 }
else {
    console.log("else block");
         var data = {
             "billing": {
                 "address_1": userForm.value.address1,
                 "address_2": "",
                 "city": userForm.value.city1,
                 "state": userForm.value.state1,
                 "postcode": userForm.value.postCode1,
                 "country": userForm.value.country1,
                 "phone": userForm.value.phone
             },
             "shipping": {
                 "address_1": userForm.value.address2,
                 "address_2": "",
                 "city": userForm.value.city2,
                 "state": userForm.value.state2,
                 "postcode": userForm.value.postCode2,
                 "country": userForm.value.country2
             },
         }
     console.log("data2",data);
              }
        
         this.http.put(SharedServiceService.getCustomer + userId, data, {
                 headers: headers
             })
             .subscribe(
                 data => {
                     this.userData = data.json();
                     console.log(this.userData);
                     this.storage.store('userInformation', this.userData);
                     var arr = data.json();
                     //          this.savedData=false;
                     //          this.editData=true;
                     this.userInfo.push(arr);
                     console.log("address ", this.userInfo);
                     this.phone = this.userInfo[0].billing.phone;
                     this.name = this.userInfo[0].username;
                     this.email = this.userInfo[0].email;
                     this.billing = this.userInfo[0].billing;
   
                     this.shipping = this.userInfo[0].shipping;
                 },
                 err => {
                     console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
                 })
     }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 mail-grid-left " data-wow-delay=".5s">
                                    <form [hidden]="savedData">
                                        <!--                                    <span style="text-align:left">Name:</span>-->
                                        <input type="text" value="{{name}}" required="" name="name" disabled>
                                        <!--                                    <label>Email:</label>-->
                                        <input type="email" value="{{email}}" required="" name="email" disabled>
                                        <!--                                    <label>Telephone:</label>-->
                                        <input type="tel" placeholder="Telephone" value="{{phone}}" required="" disabled>
                                        <label style="color:#DE865D">Billing Address:</label>
                                        <textarea type="text" placeholder="Billing Address..." required="" disabled name="shippingAdd" value="{{billing.address_1}},{{billing.phone}},{{billing.city}},{{billing.state}},{{billing.country}}"></textarea>
                                        <label style="color:#DE865D">Shipping Address:</label>
                                        <textarea type="text" placeholder="Shipping Address..." required=""  name="billingAdd" value="{{shipping.address_1}},{{shipping.city}},{{shipping.state}},{{shipping.country}}" disabled></textarea>

                                        <div class="occasion-cart" align="center">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <a class="item_add" class="hoverClass" previousStep (click)="change()" style="cursor:pointer">Change</a>
                                                <a class="item_add" class="hoverClass" style="cursor:pointer" nextStep (click)="windowTop()">Next</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <form [hidden]="editData" #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)">
                                        <!--                                    <label>Name:</label>-->
                                        <input type="text" value="{{name}}" placeholder="Enter name" required="" name="name" ngModel>
                                        <!--                                    <label>Email:</label>-->
                                        <input type="email" value="{{email}}" required="" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" ngModel>
                                        <!--                                    <label>Telephone:</label>-->
                                        <input type="tel" placeholder="Telephone" placeholder="Enter phone" required="" value="{{phone}}" name="phone" ngModel>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label style="color:#DE865D">Billing Address</label>
                                                <hr>
                                                <!--                                            <label>Address:</label>-->
                                                <textarea type="text" placeholder="Billing Address..." required="" name="address1" value="{{billing.address_1}}" placeholder="Billing Address" ngModel></textarea>
                                                <!--                                            <label>City:</label>-->
                                                <select class="form-control" placeholder="choose city" value="{{billing.city}}" name="city1" id="city1" ngModel>
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose city</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of cities" >{{data}}</option>
        </select><br>
                                                <!--                                            <label>State:</label>-->
                                                <select class="form-control" placeholder="choose state" value="{{billing.state}}" name="state1" id="state1" ngModel>
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose state</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of states" >{{data}}</option>
        </select><br>
                                                <input type="text" value="{{billing.postcode}}" placeholder="Enter postcode" required="" name="postCode1"><br> <br>
                                                <!--                                            <label>Country:</label>-->
                                                <select class="form-control" placeholder="choose country" name="country1" value="{{billing.country}}" id="country1" ngModel>
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose country</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of countries" >{{data}}</option>
        </select>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label style="color:#DE865D">Shipping Address</label>
                                                <hr>
                                                <textarea type="text" placeholder="Shipping Address..." required="" name="address2" value="{{shipping.address_1}}" ngModel></textarea>

                                                <select class="form-control" value="{{shipping.city}}" placeholder="choose city" name="city2" ngModel>
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose city</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of cities" >{{data}}</option>
        </select><br>
                                                <select class="form-control" value="{{shipping.state}}" placeholder="choose state" name="state2" ngModel>
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose state</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of states" >{{data}}</option>
        </select><br>
                                                <input type="text" value="{{shipping.postcode}}" required="" placeholder="Enter postcode" name="postCode2" ngModel>
                                                <br>
                                                <br>
                                                <select class="form-control" value="{{shipping.country}}" name="country2" placeholder="choose country" ngModel>
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose country</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of countries" >{{data}}</option>
        </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <input type="submit" class="item_add hoverClass" value="Add" nextStep (click)="windowTop()">&nbsp;
                                    <input type="submit" class="item_add hoverClass" value="Cancel" (click)="cancel()" [hidden]="cancelOption">
                                         <div class="occasion-cart" align="center" [hidden]="empty">
            </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

written another form for editing the data.I have written onsubmit function for editing the form and I need to get all the field values present in the form.My problem is Iam getting the values for the fields that user has changed,but not the remaining fields with prefilled data.I need to get the changed(modified) values along with unchanged field values(Already prefilled) in onsubmit function.Here is my code:

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the [(ngModel)] in each field of form like below:

```
<form [hidden]="editData" #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)">
                                        <!--                                    <label>Name:</label>-->
                                        <input type="text" value="{{name}}" placeholder="Enter name" required="" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
                                        <!--                                    <label>Email:</label>-->
                                        <input type="email" value="{{email}}" required="" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email">
                                        <!--                                    <label>Telephone:</label>-->
                                        <input type="tel" placeholder="Telephone" placeholder="Enter phone" required="" value="{{phone}}" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="phone">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label style="color:#DE865D">Billing Address</label>
                                                <hr>
                                                <!--                                            <label>Address:</label>-->
                                                <textarea type="text" placeholder="Billing Address..." required="" name="address1" value="{{billing.address_1}}" placeholder="Billing Address" [(ngModel)]="billing.address_1"></textarea>
                                                <!--                                            <label>City:</label>-->
                                                <select class="form-control" placeholder="choose city" value="{{billing.city}}" name="city1" id="city1" [(ngModel)]="billing.city">
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose city</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of cities" >{{data}}</option>
        </select><br>
                                                <!--                                            <label>State:</label>-->
                                                <select class="form-control" placeholder="choose state" value="{{billing.state}}" name="state1" id="state1" [(ngModel)]="billing.state">
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose state</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of states" >{{data}}</option>
        </select><br>
                                                <input type="text" value="{{billing.postcode}}" placeholder="Enter postcode" required="" name="postCode1" [(ngModel)]="billing.postcode"><br> <br>
                                                <!--                                            <label>Country:</label>-->
                                                <select class="form-control" placeholder="choose country" name="country1" value="{{billing.country}}" id="country1" [(ngModel)]="billing.country">
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose country</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of countries" >{{data}}</option>
        </select>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label style="color:#DE865D">Shipping Address</label>
                                                <hr>
                                                <textarea type="text" placeholder="Shipping Address..." required="" name="address2" value="{{shipping.address_1}}" [(ngModel)]="shipping.address_1"></textarea>

                                                <select class="form-control" value="{{shipping.city}}" placeholder="choose city" name="city2" [(ngModel)]="shipping.city">
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose city</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of cities" >{{data}}</option>
        </select><br>
                                                <select class="form-control" value="{{shipping.state}}" placeholder="choose state" name="state2" [(ngModel)]="shipping.state">
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose state</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of states" >{{data}}</option>
        </select><br>
                                                <input type="text" value="{{shipping.postcode}}" required="" placeholder="Enter postcode" name="postCode2" [(ngModel)]="shipping.postcode">
                                                <br>
                                                <br>
                                                <select class="form-control" value="{{shipping.country}}" name="country2" placeholder="choose country" [(ngModel)]="shipping.country">
                                                 <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose country</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of countries" >{{data}}</option>
        </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <input type="submit" class="item_add hoverClass" value="Add" nextStep (click)="windowTop()">&nbsp;
                                    <input type="submit" class="item_add hoverClass" value="Cancel" (click)="cancel()" [hidden]="cancelOption">
                                         <div class="occasion-cart" align="center" [hidden]="empty">
            </div>
                                    </form>
```

Comment: yeah,I have given ngModel in each form field.Even it returns empty for that particular field if it is not changed.

Comment: @srujana You should set `[(ngModel)]` to equal you prop: `[(ngModel)]="billing.address_1"` instead of setting `value`